# Visual Studio - Code slow down

Tags: visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2010, profiler, slowdown

I was messing around with profiling (sampling and instrumentation) and after doing so, for some reason my release mode code suffers from some stutters and slow downs where as it was perfect before.

I am quite new to profiling code and this was my first time running the default visual studio 2010 one.

Could it have set some project options that inject code even when not profiling?
I am running out of things to try because my actual application code has not changed that much since I was running the profiler.

Comment: Turn __off__ all profiling settings.

Comment: but how? I only found /PROFILE in linker settings, turned that off already

Comment: Just put back your backup of the sln and suo file from before you started playing with the profiling.

Comment: Did you do a 'rebuild all' after turning off profiling?

Comment: that seemed to have solved it thanks!